# How to select the average value of a calculated column in query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've written this code to select following query.

I would like to select the average value of the calculated column "delta" but I have no idea that how to do this.

```
select 
    T_event.Actie_ID, actie_omschrijving, event_timestamp, 
    left(custom1, 4) as model, custom1, Custom2, 
    cast(T_event.event_timestamp - Lag(T_event.event_timestamp) over (order by T_event.Event_ID) AS time) [Delta]
from 
    T_event
inner join 
    T_Actie ON T_event.Actie_ID = T_Actie.Actie_ID
where 
    T_EVENT.Actie_ID in (48,49,43,31,36) 
    and Event_Timestamp >= '2019-07-22'
order by 
    Event_timestamp desc
```

Comment: Sample input and output data would help your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this, by grouping with all the columns you may get the average by grouping clause. For more info you may find this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
; with cte as (
    select T_event.Actie_ID, actie_omschrijving, event_timestamp, 
        left(custom1,4) as model, custom1, Custom2, 
        cast(T_event.event_timestamp - Lag(T_event.event_timestamp) over (order by 
    T_event.Event_ID) AS time) [Delta]
    from T_event
        inner join T_Actie ON T_event.Actie_ID = T_Actie.Actie_ID
    WHERE T_EVENT.Actie_ID in (48,49,43,31,36) 
        and Event_Timestamp >= '2019-07-22'
)
select Actie_ID, actie_omschrijving, event_timestamp, model, custom1, Custom2, AVG([Delta]) 
from cte
group by Actie_ID, actie_omschrijving, event_timestamp, model, custom1, Custom2
order by Event_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator.